# Permutations with identical objects 10

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

new to MSE :) I am confused with permutation problems involving identical objects.For example set = {GGGBP} how many 2-letter strings can be produced?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting confused? Have you tried writing out all the possibilities and looking for patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ different characters to select, so the number of length $2$ strings is
$$3\cdot3-2=7$$
As this counts every combination of the $3$ letters ($3\cdot3$) except where the letters $B, P$ are selected twice ($-2$).

Comment: Thank you !! :)